# What was the character of the Sylva Sylvarum that differentiated it from previous works?

Tags: literature, science

The [Sylva Sylvarum](http://www.lib.rochester.edu/index.cfm?page=3613) (1627) is recognized as the first 'treatise on [natural history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_History)'.  Some regard it as the most-complete work, for its day.

But as early as 70AD, other works existed, such as Pliny's work on [Natural History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_History_(Pliny)).

Why was the modern of F. Bacon such a landmark?  Did he introduce some style of communicating that was wholly different?

Comment: "Science (as we think of it today), and knowledge in general, doesn't change."  I commend to you the works of Popper, Kuhn, Lakatos and Feyerabend as a start on disabusing you of this assumption.

Comment: I welcome edits rather the outright removal.  The point of the now-edited portion is that examples, like physical laws, *do not change*.  We can have misinterpreted the mechanism that caused the phenomena of which we made observations, but there exists an immutability to 'the things' that drove/underlaid the occurrences.  As such, was it the quality of Bacon's observations that made his work a milestone?  Was it something else?

Comment: "We can have misinterpreted the mechanism that caused the phenomena of which we made observations, but there exists an immutability to 'the things' that drove/underlaid the occurrences."  I still have to recommend more, much more, philosophy of science.  It isn't a wrong conception, but it isn't a conception that can be demonstrated to be correct.

Comment: So *improve*, rather than *remove*.  We're all in this together.  Look forward to your edits